# Unable to open the port by calling Native method from ITLSSPProc.dll

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna

> This is native method from ITLSSPProc.dll

```
NOMANGLE int CCONV OpenSSPComPort (SSP_COMMAND * cmd);
```

> Here, SSP_COMMAND is structure in ITLSSPProc.dll which is in C++
>   Language.

```
struct SSP_COMMAND
{
unsigned long BaudRate;
unsigned char PortNumber;
};
```

> So, I have to access OpenSSPComPort (SSP_COMMAND * cmd) in java using
>   JNI. Here is a code i have written,

```
public class Main {
    public interface ITLSSPProc extends Library {
     ITLSSPProc INSTANCE = (ITLSSPProc) Native.loadLibrary(
            (Platform.isWindows() ? "ITLSSPProc" : "simpleDLLWindowsPort"), ITLSSPProc.class);

        int OpenSSPComPort(Pointer param); 
        int CloseSSPComPort();                    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

     ITLSSPProc sdll = ITLSSPProc.INSTANCE;

        Memory intMem = new Memory(10); // allocating space
        intMem.setLong(0,9600);
        intMem.setString(1,"com7");        

        if(sdll.OpenSSPComPort(intMem)==1)
        {// calling function with int parameter&result
            System.out.println("connected");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
     }
}

Output : failed
```

> Port number is COM7 on which we are working. So, when i run this
>   application and as i passing baud rate as manually as given in user
>   manual and if port number is correct it has to print "connected" on
>   console. So, anybody know where i am going wrong, i dont understand
>   where is actual problem..

Comment: Read the JNA documentation on type mapping, specifically w/r/t mapping native `long`, `char`, and `struct` types.

Answer (score 0):

[JNA documentation for basic types](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md) (`long`, `char`).

[JNA documentation for aggregate types](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/StructuresAndUnions.md) (`struct`, `struct *`).

```
// tl;dr
class SSP_COMMAND extends Structure {
    public NativeLong BaudRate;
    public byte PortNumber;
}

int OpenSSPComPort(SSP_COMMAND param)
```

Comment: but if i taken BaudRate as NativeLong, how can i pass value 9600 to BaudRate, because this is default value given in documentation.

Comment: and we have checked port number on which hardware is connected is COM7, so how can i pass this value as byte...

Comment: According to the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475886/how-to-convert-c-language-structure-definition-into-java-code), the above isn't the complete or proper `SSP_COMMAND` definition.

Comment: are you know any way to view contents of dll file, i searched and got s/w "Depends" but it only shows method names not it's parameters, so please help me to view contents of dll file.

Comment: The information isn't contained in the DLL unless it has debug information embedded.  You'll need to find the original API documentation or [something comparable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130877/dllimport-on-c-sharp).